# Iterating through C# dictionary with KeyValuePair

Tags: c#, string, dictionary, foreach, iteration

I try to iterate through *dictionary*, but it shows me this **error**:

> "cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair' to 'string'".

Can you tell me how to solve this problem?

Here's the code:

```
var dict = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> ugh in dict){

               .............     
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: show the full code. the code shown shouldn't cause the error you've stated.

Answer (score 8):

You cannot assign a type `KeyValuePair` to a `string` instead you can extract the key and value like this:

```
var dict = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValue in dict)
{
       var key = keyValue.Key;
       var value = keyValue.Value;    
       ...
       ...          
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Following should work

```
foreach (var keyValue in dict)
{
       var key = keyValue.Key;
       var value = keyValue.Value;    
       //other logic
}
```